# Should I tip my driver in Manila when somebody else is paying?

Tags: local-customs, tipping, philippines

I'll soon visit the Philippines for business, and our local partner will be providing a car and driver. I have no idea how much he's getting paid.

**Should I tip him**, and if yes, **how much and how often**? And what if I need him outside office hours?

As a reference point, per local advice I did tip my drivers in India and Indonesia, with a little extra if they had to stay late (going to restaurants after work etc).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was in a similar situation before, I found out that drivers are on minimum wage and do not stick to office hours. Their employers usually summon them whenever they wish. So they will welcome tips and it might be a real help for them actually.

The employer was a friend/colleague, and I noticed that she tipped him, he buys the stuff with his own money (coffee or something) then when she pays him back she gives a little more (10 or 20 pesos).

When I was with the driver alone (twice) running my private errands, I tipped him at the end of the day, once 100 pesos and the second time it was 200 pesos because it was a few errands with many stops, he carried stuff for me as well, I didn't ask him but he insisted. The last day he just took me to the airport, I gave him a 10 USD bill as I was running out of pesos.

I haven't asked a local about this specific situation at the time, but I know locals do tip drivers/waiters and I did that in my previous visits. I think my estimation was right because the guy seemed happy and helpful. You might not be obliged to do so, but it's always a good idea to help people on minimum wages.

Comment: Checked with a local friend and she agreed, tips are not obligatory but definitely welcome. Apparently 300 pesos/day is the going rate, although this seems pretty high to me - the official minimum wage is only 450!

Comment: @jpatokal 450 a day? my friend pays him in monthly basis but I am not sure how much..

Comment: Yup, per day: http://www.nwpc.dole.gov.ph/pages/ncr/cmwr.html

Comment: @jpatokal thats around 270usd a month.. very low.